# $PATH is not updated

Tags: macos, bash, path, terminal

It seems all about this was already discussed, but I can't resolve my problem.
I have all necessary strings in /etc/paths

```
/usr/bin
/bin
/usr/sbin
/sbin
/usr/local/bin
```

in ~/.bash_profile

```
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/mysql/bin
export PATH=$PATH:$HOME/.rvm/bin
export PATH="$(brew --prefix php54)/bin:$PATH"
export PATH="$(brew --prefix)/bin:$PATH"
```

But every time I execute

```
echo $PATH
```

in terminal, I get only

```
/usr/local/bin
```

if I put .bash_profile strings to .profile or .bashrc I have no effect.

Comment: Have you quit terminal and retry?

Comment: yes, sure, I restarted it!

Comment: Type ". .bash_profile" to reload .bash_profile and update any functions you add.

Comment: it didn't help, I don't understand why there are no paths from /etc/paths? only /usr/local/bin

Comment: Any change if you put those lines in `.bashrc` instead?

Comment: Hm, I moved  to `.bashrc`and make empty `bash_profile` and it helped. But I believe I've made this already(:

Comment: From `man bash` `When bash is invoked as an interactive login shell, or as a non-interactive  shell  with  the  --login
       option,  it  first reads and executes commands from the file /etc/profile, if that file exists.  After
       reading that file, it looks for ~/.bash_profile, ~/.bash_login, and ~/.profile,  in  that  order,`

Comment: You sure there's no such line somewhere in your .bash_profile or .bashrc: `export PATH=/usr/local/bin`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

PATH is constructed first from /etc/paths, then from the files in /etc/paths.d, and then from .bash_profile. Starting from the last step, methodically remove each step, and test to see if your problem is recreated.

1. Comment out every line in .bash_profile and save (or you could delete/rename it).
2. Close out your terminal and restart it to reconstruct your PATH.
3. echo $PATH. It should contain everything from /etc/paths.

If everything from /etc/paths is included, then your problem lies in your .bash_profile. Uncomment one line at a time until you recreate your problem. Then you will know which line is your problem, and will be able to troubleshoot that instead of a vague PATH issue.

Alternatively, if deleting .bash_profile has no effect, then you have a problem that's occurring before .bash_profile acts. Check the files in /etc/paths.d - those also get appended to your PATH. Move them out of paths.d and then test whether your PATH is properly constructed from /etc/paths.

It seems like a lot of people have some trouble with rvm, as in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18317793/2572762) [and this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12810020/2572762) , so I'm guessing the problem lies in your .bash_profile. Good luck and let us know.

Answer (score 4):

Do this in the shell:

```
$ source ~/.bashrc
```

This makes the current session aware of the change.

Answer (score 1):

Alternate approach to trouble shoot, (It just worked for me and this is for osx users).

1. Got to /Users/username/
2. Now press cmd + shift + . (Now all hidden files will be visible)
3. Try to open the .bash_profile file and see your PATH item exists or not
4. Comment items and echo $PATH and verify the edits are getting reflected.
5. If not may be you are using zsh, so try editing the .zprofile

Comment: Thanks! I was using zsh and editing the .zprofile did the trick! After that, I executed the `source ~/.zprofile` command to refresh the session.

Answer (score 0):

There could be spaces in the value of PATH and might be causing problems with it. Try placing it inside quotes:

```
export PATH="$PATH:/usr/local/mysql/bin"
export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.rvm/bin"
export PATH="$(brew --prefix php54)/bin:$PATH"
export PATH="$(brew --prefix)/bin:$PATH"
```

Even though it's kind of unlikely with export. Perhaps the script is parsed in a different way.

Comment: I still have no effect! I even have no /usr/bin in PATH.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting the `$PATH` variable at the end of the line. In my `.bash_profile` that is how I have it and it works fine.

```
export PATH="/usr/local/mysql/bin:$PATH"
```